# What does it mean by "error: not declared in this scope?"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    do
    {
    string name, answer;
    cout << "Welcome to the prime number checker! Please enter your name: ";
    getline (cin, name);
    int a;
    cout << "\nHello " << name;
    cout << "\nPlease enter an integer: ";
    cin >> a;
    cin.sync();
    if (a == 2)
    {
        cout << "\nThis is a prime number" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int b = 2; b < a; b++)
        {
            if (a % b == 0)
            {
                cout << "This number is not prime number" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "This number is a prime number." << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Do you want to do this again (Yes or No)?";
    getline (cin, answer);
    }
    while (answer == "yes" || answer == "YES" || answer == "Yes"); //Not declared in this scope
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, you can improve the performance of your prime number detection algorithm by only checking against `2` and odd numbers. ;) Change your inner `for` loop to count from `3` to `sqrt(a)`, incrementing `b` by two each time.

Comment: answer is hidden from while condition so make it upper outside the loop

Answer (score 2):

You declared `answer` within the `do` block.  But then try to reference `answer` outside of that scope block.

Declare `answer` at the top of `main` instead of in the `do` block.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the declaration of `answer` outside the loop:

```
string answer;
do {
   string name;
   ...
} while (answer == "yes" || answer == "YES" || answer == "Yes");
```

If you declare it inside the loop, it no longer exists by the time the `while` clause is evaluated.

Comment: One might also (cautiously) be inclined to note that things become quite a bit more obvious this type of indentation ...

Answer (score 0):

As other people said, the "answer" variable only exists inside the loop - it isn't accessible from outside it.

One other recommendation: rather than checking every possible permutation of capitalization just cast the whole string to lowercase. (You actually missed several - there are 6 total because each position could have one of 2 possible values. Presumably something like "YeS", for example, should still be accepted as "yes").